# Authentication fails when submit the photo using FileTransfer object

Tags: cordova, struts2, cordova-3

I am trying to upload a picture to server using phonegap FileTransfer, When I submit the picture to server it gets "Login credentials not provided: Bad request"

Here I am binding the login credentials with option Object, but it fails every time submit the picture to server

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+'.jpg';
        options.mimeType="image/jpg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.username = PortalDB.getUserName();
        params.password = PortalDB.getPassword();

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(servicet.serviceURL+"documentSupport!uploadDocument.action"), self.uploadCompleted, self.uploadFailed, options);
```

Here my authentication filter code

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        LOGGER.info("Authenticating service request");

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest   = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        LOGGER.info("Intercepting : " + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());

        String userName         = httpServletRequest.getParameter("username");
        String password         = httpServletRequest.getParameter("password");
        String clientTimeZoneId = httpServletRequest.getParameter("clientTimeZoneId");

        if (userName == null || userName.trim().length() == 0 
                || password == null || password.trim().length() == 0) {

            LOGGER.info("Login credentails not provided: Bad request");
            httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(LOGIN_REQUIRED); 
            return;

        } else if (httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute(CoreConstants.SESSION_USER) == null) {

            LOGGER.info("Finding user " + userName);

            try {

                User user = commonSecurityManager.getUser(userName);

                if (user == null) {
                    LOGGER.info("User not found. Authentication failed");
                    httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(USER_NOT_FOUND);
                    return;
                }

                if (!user.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password)) {
                    LOGGER.info("Invalid password. Authentication failed");
                    httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(INVALID_PASSWORD);
                    return;
                }

                LOGGER.info("Adding user to session " + userName);

                user.setBrowserTimeZoneId(clientTimeZoneId);
                httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(CoreConstants.SESSION_USER, user);
                httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(CoreConstants.BROWSER_TIMEZONE_ID, clientTimeZoneId);

            } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
                LOGGER.info("User not found. Authentication failed");
                httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(USER_NOT_FOUND);
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                httpServletRequest.getSession().invalidate();
                LOGGER.error("Error Occurred While Obtaining user ", e);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Here username and password does not include in the httpServlet,I want to know how to bind authentication parameter using FileTransfer object

Comment: Why do you using a filter? Struts2 can be configured to intercept each action invocation.